# Linux command to find all *.rb files

Tags: find

I still can't figure out how to use the Linux find command.  I'm trying to find all the .rb files under the `/var/www` directory.  What's the correct command to type in Bash?

Comment: This might help someone while looks for the same in future. https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/25-examples-of-find-commands-in-linux/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

find /var/www -name  "*.rb"